# Ubuntu 14.04 READ ONLY SYSTEM

Tags: read-only

i am new with ubuntu and i installed 14.04, but from the first boot i have a read only system. I can't download or copy files and it is very frustating. Please help me guys i searched online but nothing worket for me.

Comment: Explain how you install ubuntu and how are you copying files and where, please.

Comment: I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 for om the official website and used Rufus to make a bootable USB and installed it. For ex I can't edit my computer make now folders or download something

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem probably entered RO mode because there was/is an inconsistency.

Boot from a live DVD and run

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda1
```

(Replacing /dev/sda1 accordingly)

Comment: It says that command is not found...